# How to approach long column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns, names

I have a large data-set comprised of many very specific variables. I am looking for a way to simplify the column names using a quick method rather than manually changing over 1000 columns.

```
total.population.2020 <- c("1","2" )
total.population.2020.both.sexes <- c("3", "4")
total.population.2020.sexes.males.14.to.16.years <- c("7", "9")
total.income.2020 <- c("55", "40")
total.income.2020.25.to.30.years <- c("80", "90")
            
df <- data.frame(total.population.2020, total.population.2020.both.sexes, total.population.2020.sexes.males.14.to.16.years, total.income.2020, total.income.2020.25.to.30.years)
```

I ran the clean_names function from Janitor first because using gsub/abbreviate on the original df would wipe out the whole column name leaving it empty rather than simplifying it.

```
library(janitor)
df <- clean_names(df)
```

Then I would run gsub/abbreviate. However I am running into the problem that the abbreviations are still very long (10 characters+) and missing numbers that I would count as important identifiers (ex. Age 20 to 25). This requires me to still manually change the column names.

```
names(df) <- abbreviate(gsub("_", " ", names(df)))
df
```

Is there a simpler method? How would you approach a large data-set with long column names?

Expected Output:

| Old | New |
| --- | --- |
| `total.population.2020` | tp |
| `total.population.2020.both.sexes` | tpb |
| `total.population.2020.sexes.males.14.to.16.years` | tpm14_16 |
| `total.income.2020` | ti |
| `total.income.2020.25.to.30.years` | ti25_30 |

Comment: This is better.  It still might not be super-easy.   You could start by using something like `gsub("(.).*\\.", "\\1", nm)` to grab only the first letter of each dot-separated element (or use `strsplit` with a dot-separator first, then use `substr` to get the first letter); then apply other special-case rules like converting "20xx" to "xx" when xx are numeric; etc. (More fussing around with regexes than I have time for right now ...)

Comment: There is another issue with that expectected.  Suppose yu have a column name with `"total.population.2021". I assume your New is takingthe first 2 digits ? or last 2 digits?  Also `total.income.2020.25.to.30.years` the expected is ti25_30 if there is 2021, it duplicates

Comment: @akrun There is no 2021, all the data comes from the same year (2020 for this example). I will correct the post and the 20 can be removed from new.

Comment: I think an easy way would be to create a lookup table (similar to your expected output) and change the column names by matching the column names with that data.

Comment: @RonakShah Wouldn't a lookup table mean I would need to manually create 1000+ variable names? Or would there be a faster method than manually inputting variable name by variable name in a table?

Comment: @BenBolker I think your suggestion is the solution I am going with. I am new to Regex so I have been learning and playing around with it. I have made some progress with it but still need more experience on my part. Thanks for the guidance.